# profit of limited length datatype

Tags: oracle, ddl

Is there any profit to limit datatype while declaring a table if data length limit is known beforehand?

```
create table "user"."table" (
    ...
    "is_there_any_profit" number (1, 0)
)
```

vs

```
create table "user"."table" (
    ...
    "is_there_any_profit" number
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically not, all numbers are stored same way (mantissa + exponent). The profit is in business logic rules implementation. If you expect to store whole numbers into database, it is good idea to enforce this by setting correct datatype (e.g. NUMBER(10,0)). You declare, that other values are invalid.

Comment: The same goes for any datatype. For varchar, you better make sure somehow that you can handle up to 4000 char or bytes (depending on the database's settings) in your (front-end) code for those fields.

Comment: @colin. not really for VARCHAR2's. you need to be careful there as it's not just a client thing. there's real problems if you blindly just allocate 4000 for every field. you really give the CBO a hard time for one thing, and you would soon hit composite indexing issues (key length exceeded) on any data model that's decided to just stick varchar2(4000) on every field.

Comment: Good points. And I remember also some post about some application server performing very badly because it allocated lots of memory -- which wasn't actually needed.